# my website is close " HTTP ERROR 500 "

Tags: php, apache-2.4, wordpress, 500-error

my website is close
error is "  [www.worldtourjourney.com](http://www.worldtourjourney.com) is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"
please help me
how can i resolve this error ?

My website appears to be offline or unresponsive.

when I am trying to open my website and Wordpress dashboard it says-
Please guide me on how I can recover or solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server (usually located under `/var/log`), there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions on the server for the directories and files. That is a common problem.